# How to specify a custom autocomplete for specific commands?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Is there a way to have bash know exactly what to display when you double tab? For example I have a python script `scpy` which requires a couple arguments. For example like `apt-get`, if you double tab gives you

```
autoclean        build-dep        clean            dselect-upgrade  purge            source           upgrade
autoremove       check            dist-upgrade     install          remove           update
```

Is there a way to do that for your own scripts/programs? Do I need to wrap my python script in a bash script?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to include a shell script in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.  The basic structure of this file is a simple function that performs the completion and then invocation of `complete` which is a bash builtin.  Rather than go into detail on how to use `complete`, I suggest you read [An Introduction to Bash Completion](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1).  Part 1 covers the basics and Part 2 gets into how you would go about writing a completion script.

A denser description of bash completion can be found in the "Programmable Completion" section of `man bash` (you can type "/Programmable Completion" and then press 'n' a few times to get there quickly.  Or, if you are feeling luck, "g 2140 RETURN").

Comment: That looked promising, but the link is dead.

Comment: [Archive of Part 1 (from 2019)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190328055722/https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1)

  [Part 2 (2014)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140405211529/http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2)

Answer (score 16):

Here is basic guide.

Lets have an example of script called `admin.sh` to which you would like to have autocomplete working.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  arg=$1

  case $arg in
    option_1)
     # do_option_1
    ;;
    option_2)
     # do_option_1
    ;;
    shortlist)
      echo option_1 option_2 shortlist
    ;;
    *)
     echo Wrong option
    ;;
  esac
  
  shift
done
```

Note option `shortlist`. Calling script with this option will print out all possible options for this script.

And here you have the `autocomplete.sh` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

_script() {
  _script_commands=$(/path/to/your/admin.sh shortlist)

  local cur prev
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${_script_commands}" -- ${cur}) )
  return 0
}

complete -o nospace -F _script /path/to/your/admin.sh
```

Note that the last argument to complete is the name of the script you want to add autocompletion to. All you need to do is to add your autocomplete script to `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash_completion.d` as:

```bash
source /full-path/to/your/autocomplete.sh

# or

. /full-path/to/your/autocomplete.sh
```

Finally, make them executable:

```bash
chmod a+x admin.sh autocomplete.sh
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/483149/24155

Comment: 'complete tutorial' is not the phrase I would use to describe this...

Comment: I'm confused, is `/path/to/your/script.sh` the same file you called `./admin.sh` later in the script?

And what do you do if you didn't author the script, so you can't add a `shortlist` subcommand? 

This also doesn't really seem like standard practice.

Comment: @joshtch Post updated. May be you will be interested on https://github.com/reduardo7/bashx too