# An easy bash completion tutorial?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I want to learn how to write bash completion scripts. Which tutorial would you recommend?

Comment: What do you mean by "bash completion tutorial"? Please explain.

Comment: the explanation is needed on the word "tutorial", what do you actually need?

Comment: @Tshepang: I guess you mean you want to learn how to write bash completion routines?  Using bash completion is pretty easy, you just hit the `tab` key.

Comment: You may want to check out the link I provide in my answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/custom-autocomplete

Comment: so this will become a duplicate I guess

Comment: @Tshepang People don't generally delete comments, particularly ones that are still valid like Steven's. Keep in mind that the answers here aren't just for you -- they're for everyone who googles "bash completion tutorial" in the future

Comment: How come this question is considered "too broad" ? That's ridiculous. It's perfectly valid, and answers provided prove it's not so easy to find out.

Comment: The Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide is always a good starting point: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html

Comment: Hi @terdon, since this question is rightfully closed, can a question this was flagged as a dupe of be reopened? http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1800 is a good question, and should be reopened if this one is closed.

Comment: @cat fair enough, done.

Comment: I recommend next: http://askubuntu.com/a/483149/24155

Comment: I wrote one, you can find it here: https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial.html

Answer (score 60):

There aren't that many bash completion tutorials around, but this one is pretty good:

[Introduction to Bash Completion](http://web.archive.org/web/20200726061552/https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1)

- Part 1 is for general knowledge
- Part 2 covers creating scripts in /etc/bash_completion.d/

Answer (score 22):

I would start by looking at the library of bash completions already put together by the folks here:

[http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/](http://web.archive.org/web/20110504183833/http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/)

They also have a mailing list:

http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/bash-completion-devel

Comment: Link is not working

Comment: It's appears dead since around may.
The archive is only moderately useful, as it redirects to the corresponding github repo.
https://web.archive.org/web/20180507171315/http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/

Comment: That Github repo being here: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion